# C#.net winforms: Unable to store captcha into picturebox

Tags: c#, captcha

I'm trying to get a captcha from a 3rd party website and store it into a picturebox.

Here is the captcha url: http://www.lbj00.com/ValidationControls.aspx?

Using Google chrome I could view the captcha.
Sample image:
[Sample image from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFcmA.png)

But getting it to work in C#.net seems there is a problem. So far I have tried to use another captcha url: http://www.xl18.biz/general/captcha.aspx from a different 3rd party website and it could store it in a picturebox without a problem.

Here is a sample code what I have from a class:

```
public static Stream GetStream(string url,out string refcookies)
{
   HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;
   HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest;

   httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
   httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
   httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
   httpWebRequest.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=0";
   httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   httpWebRequest.Referer = url;
   httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
   httpWebRequest.Proxy = null;
   httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
   httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

   try
   {
       httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
   }
   catch (WebException wex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(wex.Message);
   }

   refcookies = ""; //out string parameter
   foreach (Cookie ck in httpWebResponse.Cookies)
   {
       refcookies += ck.Name + "=" + ck.Value + "; ";
   }

   try
   {
       using (Stream inStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
       {
              MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              int size = 0;
              while ((size = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length)) > 0)
              {
                 outStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
              }
              return outStream;
       }       
   }
   catch
   {
       if (httpWebResponse != null)
       {
           httpWebResponse.Close();
           httpWebResponse = null;
       }
       return null;
       //throw;
   }
   finally
   {
       httpWebRequest = null;
   }
}
```

Here is a sample code I have from a button to store it in the picturebox:

```
string cookies;
Stream s;
s = Http.GetStream(codeUrl, out cooikes);
Image image = Image.FromStream(s); //returns an error here - System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'
byte[] data;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
     ms.Position = 0;
     data = new byte[ms.Length];
     ms.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length));
     pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
     ms.Flush();
}
```

**[Update]**
Could this be a problem from the server of the 3rd party website?
- not a server issue, seems that the response value is a _incapsula_resource.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Steam `s` length is grater than 0? I mean are you getting response properly?

Comment: @GaurangDave, yes Steam s is greater than 0, and I'm getting response even the cookie returned some value.

Comment: Try `Image image = Image.FromStream(s, true, false);` I mean check overloads of `FromStream()`

Comment: Just a side not about your try/catch pattern: if GetResponse throws and exception you are done for the rest of your method as httpWebResponse is null.

Comment: @GaurangDave, tried using it Image image = Image.FromStream(s, true, false); but produce same result

Comment: @PepitoSh, yes, but through testing stream have always a value though, I could try to improve it later on.

Answer (score 0):

The stream GetStream returns is not in the required format.

Check the httpWebResponse properties upon arrival, particularly the ContentType. It should be image/png or similar. Most probably the stream you receive from it is not ONLY the image binary but other values as well.

Comment: the response.ContentType is text/html

Comment: Is this a server issue then? But when I tried it using google chrome, in response headers the content type have a value of image/jpeg.

Comment: It depends on the contract you have with that server. If the server specifies that the response is a text, maybe an image base64 encoded, then it is your responsibility to process the response to extract the image.

If the response is an error message, then you should read and understand the content.

It is your code's problem that you try to use a stream as an image when it is in fact NOT a stream of an image.

Comment: I have found out what is the content of the response, it is _incapsula_resource.

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reason the server changed it response based from what I have set in the request headers.

**These are the only request headers I managed to set to make it work the rest in the code you will find in the above question is removed:**

```
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
httpWebRequest.Referer = url;
httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
```

So far now the response is successfully converted into stream and managed to store it within the picturebox. Both urls mentioned above in my question are working using only those headers.